# Weight file use for different size image

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train CNN where image-dimension is 128*512, then I want to use this weight file to train other data which has 128*1024 dimension. That means I want to use pre-trained weight file during the training time of different data(128*1024).

Is it possible or How can I do it?

I want to do this because I have only 300 images which have 128*1024 dimension, while I have 5000 images which have 128*512 dimension and both datasets are different.

Thank you

Comment: You can reuse the first few layers of your CNN since the sizes of weights are invariant with the input size. Do you have fully connected layer(s) at the end?

Comment: It depends on the network you use. If you create a fully-CNN, it's possible to reuse all the weights from the smaller images. If you use a Flatten() layer with a Dense() the last past need to be recomputed as the size will be different.

Comment: No, I don't have fully connected layer at the end. I am using UNet

Answer (score 1):

If your model is fully CNN, there is absolutely no need to have different models.

A CNN model can take images of any size. Just make sure the `input_shape=(None,None,channels)`

You will need separate numpy arrays though, one for the big images, another for the small images, and you will have to call a different fit method for each.

(But probably you will be working with a generator anyway)